# Function that uses SQLite3 using a lot of RAM, do I have a memory leak?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, sqlite

I have a function with a select statement that gets some information from one table and uses part of that information to use another select statement to get more information from another table.  The function then adds information from both tables into an array of objects.

Seems simple enough but each time the ViewController that uses the function is loaded the memory usage goes up and never back down again.  If I comment out the call to this function then memory usage appears fine.

```
-(void)displayExhibitor
{

    arrayOfExhibitors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &congressDB) == SQLITE_OK){

        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatementExhibitor;
        NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Exhibitor ORDER BY Name"];
        const char *sqlQueryChars = [sqlQuery UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare(congressDB, sqlQueryChars, -1, &sqlStatementExhibitor, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {

            while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatementExhibitor)==SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatementExhibitor, 1)];
                NSString *category = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatementExhibitor, 4)];
                NSString *description = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatementExhibitor, 5)];
                NSString *locationID = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatementExhibitor, 3)];
                NSString *location;
                // Get exhibitor location information from location table
                sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatementLocation;
                NSString *sqlQueryLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Name FROM Location WHERE _ID = '%@'", locationID];
                const char *sqlQueryCharsLocation = [sqlQueryLocation UTF8String];

                 if (sqlite3_prepare(congressDB, sqlQueryCharsLocation, -1, &sqlStatementLocation, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {

                     while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatementLocation)==SQLITE_ROW) {

                         location = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatementLocation, 0)];

                     }

                 } else {

                     NSLog(@"There was a problem with get location - %s",sqlite3_errmsg(congressDB));

                 }
                 sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatementLocation);

                Exhibitor *exhibitor = [[Exhibitor alloc] init];
                [exhibitor setName:name];
                [exhibitor setCategory:category];
                [exhibitor setDescription:description];
                [exhibitor setLocation:location];

                [arrayOfExhibitors addObject:exhibitor];

            }

        } else {

            NSLog(@"There was a problem with prepare- %s",sqlite3_errmsg(congressDB));

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatementExhibitor);

    } else {

        NSLog(@"There was a problem with DB open - %s",sqlite3_errmsg(congressDB));

    }

    [[self tableView]reloadData];

}
```

Is it because I have a SQLite3_prepare inside another one?

**EDIT:**
I have just tried to strip the code right down to bare minimum:

```
-(void)testFunction
{
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatementExhibitor;
    NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Exhibitor ORDER BY Name"];
    const char *sqlQueryChars = [sqlQuery UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &congressDB) == SQLITE_OK){
        if (sqlite3_prepare(congressDB, sqlQueryChars, -1, &sqlStatementExhibitor, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatementExhibitor)==SQLITE_ROW) {  
                NSLog(@"Row found");
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"There was a problem with prepare- %s",sqlite3_errmsg(congressDB)); 
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatementExhibitor);
    }
}
```

Still getting about 250KB added to the memory usage each time it runs, what is going on?  Is there a way I can manually deallocate the SQL connections from memory?

Comment: Is that the entire function?

Comment: Yeah that's it.  There is more code for the whole ViewController.m file but this is the function that appears to be the culprit i.e. if I comment this out, the memory problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to [close](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) the database connection.
This will leak the database object itself and all the page cache.

Comment: I had assumed (and read) that the 'correct' way to use SQLite3 in iOS applications was to open the database once, when the app started, and to close it once, just as the app is about to close.  Is this not the case?  Is it better to open the database just before I need it and close it just after?

Comment: But you are not opening it once; you are opening a new connection in every function call.

Comment: I had completely missed the fact that I was indeed opening a new connection each time with - if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &congressDB) == SQLITE_OK){ - it's not just checking a connection, it's opening one.  Thanks for pointing that out.